# calculating div size from another div

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to set `#div1 size width: 100% - (#div2 width + 4% )`
Is it possible?

The divs are aligned horizontally, div2 has a fixed width value of 356 px, and div1 should be the remaining horizontal space, minus 4% ...

The 4% i can add as div2 margin, but i still can't set the value to occupy the rest of the space... (it can't be a fixed value because the page is responsive...)

I've already tried using a value like 59%, but when i shrink the page, it jumps a line...

```css
.site-wrap {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  position: relative;
  top: -18;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#div2 {
  margin: 15px auto auto auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
}
#div1 {
  margin: 15px 15px auto auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 587px;
  width: 59%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrap">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you wanna achieve?

Comment: Please can you provide the html markup for the divs

Comment: @PraveenKumar i'm trying to achieve two divs at same line, one with fixed size, other with variable size that occupies the remaining space...

Comment: also was wondering if t possible to calculate a dive size with another divs...

Comment: No need. Show us your markup!

Comment: <-------------- html -------------->
<div class="site-wrap">
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
</div>

<-------------- css -------------->

.site-wrap{
 min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
    position: relative;
    top: -18;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    
}

#div2{
 margin: 15px auto auto auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 float: right;
 
}

#div1{
 margin: 15px 15px auto auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 587px;
 width: 59%;
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use positioning for this case. This is a case of:

```
+-------+-----------+
| 356px | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-------+-----------+
| 356px | FLUUUUUID |
|       | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Fixed-Fluid Model. In my snippet, I have demonstrated two kinds of examples. In the first case, the fluid is less in size. And the next has too long content.

**Snippet**

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; padding-left: 100px;}
.parent .fixed {position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}
.parent .fluid {background-color: #f99;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque animi placeat, expedita tempora explicabo facilis nulla fuga recusandae officia, maiores porro eaque, dolore et modi in sapiente accusamus id aut.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndréMata, please note that with this answer, if your fixed content is taller than your fluid content, you are going to have layout issues - http://jsfiddle.net/3oqfbpvs/.  I would always advise against absolute positioning for a 2 column layout

Comment: Thank you for the advertising @Pete ! In this case the height is the same, so it shouldn't be an issue, but i think i'll change it anyway! thanks!!

Comment: Using tables is not a good idea. Because this works in all browsers, but using tables have negative results in IE.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, tables should never be used for layout (unless making an email template), but it will work in all browsers.  Not sure why you are telling OP not to use tables as no one has used any tables.  I have used `display:table`, which is a completely different thing and will work in all browsers back to ie8, if you still need to support that.

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors and personal experience, working with all kinds of IE $h!t. @Pete!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that. Css

```
#responsive {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 356px);
  float: left;
}

#fixed {
  background: blue;
  height: 10px;
  width: 356px;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="responsive"></div>
<div id="fixed"></div>
```